# Disable prefetch on SWR

Tags: reactjs, axios, vercel, swr

I am trying to implement swr library for my data fetching. I used to use plain axios and some custom hooks I created.
The problem I am having is that for some reason, swr is firing the get request before the default axios header is set, thus missing on sending a header that is needed to identify the account for my application.
My guess is that it has to do with the prefetch capabilities of SWR but that is just a wild guess and don't know how to prevent this from happening.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, {useLayoutEffect} from "react";
import useSWR from "swr";


function Child({match}) {
    const fetcher = () => {
        console.log('Should happen second')
        axios.get('https://api.mydomain.com').then(res => res.data)
    }

    const {data} = useSWR('/account/specific/data', fetcher)

    return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
}

export default function Account({match}) {

    let accountId = match.params.accountId;

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        console.log('Should happen first')
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Account-Token"] = accountId;
    }, [accountId]);

    return <Child/>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting your sequences wrong imo.

**1) You should probably return null if your component is not ready to be generated.**

```
export default function Account({match}) {

    let accountId = match.params.accountId;

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        console.log('Should happen first')
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Account-Token"] = accountId;
    }, [accountId]);
    
    if (!accountId) return null  //<-- don't generate the Child component until you are ready.

    return <Child/>
}
```

**2) If you really want to disable SWR fetch on mount, it's to set { revalidaOnMount: false }**

e.g.

```
const {data} = useSWR('/account/specific/data', fetcher, { revalidateOnMount: false})
```

**3) Or you can use conditional fetching so it fetches only when your variable is ready.**

```
const { data } = useSWR( accountID ? /url/path : null, fetcher )
```

The useSWR hook will not call the fetcher when the key is null.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Option 1 and 2 are not work working. And option 3 I didn't try because I do not have accountId available at the moment of invoking useSWR. There is a reason why I am setting this value in a default axios header and that is to avoid sending to all data fetching operations through out the code. Setting  initialData and revalidateOnMount: true did work

Comment: Also, accountID is ready on first render since it is taken from the route params and does not depend on any async operation.

Answer (score 1):

You are using axios without **async** and **await** , also you don't have a **return** in the method fetcher, change this method in the next way:

```js
    const fetcher = async () => {
        return await axios.get('https://api.mydomain.com').then(res => res.data)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve the problem adding initialData to the options on useSWR hook.

```
    const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/data', fetcher, initialData: [], revalidateOnMount: true)
```